how to automatically connect GitHub issues (and PRs) to releases
Some repositories display the link between a closed issue and the first release the fix appeared in (see screenshot from the Celery project). I've spent some time in GitHub's documentation but can't figure out how to do this: help would be greatly appreciated.

The trick here is that “Release 5.3 (#7605)” is not actually a release. It is an issue with a task list instead.
(Would sure be nice if GitHub did this for Releases that references PRs that fixed an issue!)
